# Entity Framework Database first from non-English DB

Tags: entity-framework, generator, translation, dbcontext, non-english

I'd like to use DB first Entity Framework, but my source DB is not in English.
Is there a way to intercept the DbContext models generation, and provide a map for some/all table and column names (other language column name -> English column name)?
I'm not sure if there's a possibility to use T4 templates for this.

Comment: T4 templates in't only a possibility, it's the only way. There is no interception framework for database-first model creation. But until you show some implementation code this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was another approach available, and it seemed more suited for me, so I took it.
The main edmx file of EF turns out to be just an XML document, so I created a CSV map file between old/non-English table/column names and created a small nodejs script to replace all occurrences of:

```
<Property Name="OLD_NAME"
<ScalarProperty Name="OLD_NAME"
<PropertyRef Name="OLD_NAME"
```

..with new/model names. I applied it on edmx model and mappings sections only, and though not a complete solution it took me 95% there. I still have to rename NavigationProperties, but I'll do it in the edmx designer manually since there aren't many of those.